# how to setCookie in testcafe with redirect?

Tags: testing, cookies, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

My web application redirects any unauthenticated user to the external authentication application.
Using `setCookie` doesn't work since the page redirect before the `setCookie` finishes.

Can I disable the redirect somehow?
Or another solution?

Comment: Does this mean that you already have the correct cookie to pass to the `setCookie` method?

If so, you can try to not specify the `page` in the `fixture.page` method. Try to call `setCookie` in the test code and then use `t.navigateTo('your url')`.
If this does not help, please share the url to your project to demonstrate the issue.